# Check for XML header

Tags: xslt

How can i check in XSLT that an XML contains XML headers?

Example XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Data>
        <test>1</test>
    </Data>
```

I want to check if the `<?xml/>` header exists.

```
<xsl:if test="xml header exists">
  do something
</xsl:if>
// otherwise?
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail by what you mean by an "XML header"? Showing an example of such an XML would help. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

The `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>` is called the [XML declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-XMLDecl) and it is not part of the [XSLT/XPath/XQuery data model](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/) so you can't access it or check for it using XSLT/XPath/XQuery.